# How can an UITableViewCell stay highlighted even after reloadData?

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

If `reloadData` is called the selected `UITableViewCell` doesn't stay highlighted. So I have to remember the `NSIndexPath` of the selected cell (no multiple selection). But if I want to use `setHighlighted` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` than the cell does not get highlighted. If I do this in a method of the `UITableViewController` then the cell gets highlighted!?

Beside this problem I experienced another thing. I got a kind of multiple selection if I use `setHighlighted` together with the "normal" selection so that two cells were highlighted at the same time (which they shouldn't). I tried to undo the highlight with `deselectRowAtIndexPath` but that does nothing. It only works in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with the current index path or outside in a method of `UITableViewController` only in conjunction with `reloadData` afterwards.

I'm experiencing this on iOS 7 and iOS 8. Here is a sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"testCell"];

    UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(void)refreshPropertyList:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSIndexPath *temp = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:temp];
    [cell setHighlighted:true];
    self.selectedIndexPath  = temp;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedIndexPath]) {
        [cell setHighlighted:YES];
    }
    else {
        [cell setHighlighted:NO];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath animated:false];

    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

How can an `UITableViewCell` stay highlighted even after `reloadData`?

Comment: Try to use [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath...] after reloadData

Comment: Thanks Scott. Currently I exeperienced no other problems with it. So it seems to work. But why is this strange behavior of `setHighlighted` and `deselectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one line code to select a row

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Selected and highlighted are different. So you can't deselect the highlighted state. Visit: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setSelected:animated:

Comment: But the background should get the highlighted state if I use `setHighlighted` with YES? The documentation only talkes about the label of the cell ... So is that the difference between highlight (only label) and selected (background)?

Comment: The documentation talks: "The highlighting affects the appearance of labels, image, and background."

Comment: The same goes for `selected`: "*The selection affects the appearance of labels, image, and background. When the selected state of a cell is set to YES, it draws the **background for selected cells with its title in white***". In addition to `highlighted`: "*When the highlighted state of a cell is set to YES, **labels are drawn in their highlighted text color** (default is white).*" So the only difference I can find is label and background handling.